# check C# Action/Lambda/Delegate contains any code/statements

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, lambda

Can anyone tell me if there a way to see if an action contains any code?

```
Action x = new Action(()=>
             {

             });
```

should return false, while

```
Action x = new Action(()=>
             {
                var x = "i am a string" 
             });
```

should return true.

Perhaps using reflection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
        Action x = new Action(() =>
        {
            var xx = "i am a string";
        });


        Action x1 = new Action(() =>
        {

        });

        MethodBody mb = x.Method.GetMethodBody();
        MethodBody mb1 = x1.Method.GetMethodBody();

        byte[] b = mb.GetILAsByteArray();
        byte[] b1 = mb1.GetILAsByteArray();
```

b1 (empty method body) has only 2 bytes, values 0 and 42 meaning **nop** and **return**, I think.